# Use of chief as equivalent of boss

Tags: word-usage, nouns

According to the [OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/chief_2), the noun **chief** can be used for

> a person with a high rank or the highest rank in a company or an
>   organization.

However, while it of course appears in CEO and other job titles, I would always prefer to call refer to my line manager as **my boss** rather than **my chief**. Is this consistent with the usage by native speakers or does it depend on the region?

Comment: It doesn't just depend on region, it depends on the argot within the organization. If you join a company where everyone refers to his or her supervisor as *supes*, you will too, even if no one does so at any other company in town. *Chief* is well-ingrained in U.S. medical settings, for example, for specific positions.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking about how one may refer or talk about someone like that, or about how to call them to their face. That is, can you create a sentence for which you want to check its viability. eg 'My boss just asked me to walk his dog.' and 'Hey, boss, your dog walks very fast.'. Are you asking about 'chief' in those positions or for something else?

Comment: I'm interested in the former.

Comment: I would say "my boss" but I would never say "my chief". "Chief" is really only used adjectivally or in certain specific titles, like the C-suite positions, but also as @choster mentioned in certain types of organizations like medical or military ones, where certain management positions have "chief" in the title.

Answer (score 1):

**boss**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/21776?rskey=3hyq3C&result=6&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> An original American equivalent of ‘master’ in the sense of employer
>   of labour; applied also to a business manager, or any one who has a
>   right to give orders. In England at first only in workmen's slang, or
>   humorously, = ‘leading man, swell, top-sawyer’; now in general use in
>   Britain.

This consistent with the usage by native speakers Ame. It is used in corporate America and in the American military with combat deployed units.

Answer (score 0):

## Chief is used in a more blue-collar context than boss.

Basically, "chief" would refer to something like a shift chief or a floor chief: a high-ranking blue-collar worker who supervises other blue-collar workers. "Boss", on the other hand, would refer to any management personnel. So "my chief" would specifically be a blue-collar supervisor, while "my boss" would be anyone above them in the management chain.